# How to use UTF-8 in a RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding

I open a file in RichTextBox but accents are replaced by question marks.
So I want to use `UTF-8` encoding when opening the file.

This is all my code:

```
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
```

Comment: Is the File content saved as UTF8? Then use the [overload of ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.readalltext) that allows to specify  an encoding, adding `Encoding.UTF8`. Then, can the Font used in `RichTextBox1` reproduce the symbols you want to show?

Comment: Yes, the font reproduce. Where I need to put Encodint.UTF8 ?

Comment: I linked the MSDN reference in my previous comment. You didn't say whether the file content is UTF8-encoded. If it's not, you probably get garbage back. If it's ASCII you have the same result. If it's - as often improperly referred to - ANSI (local Encoding), use the local encoding (`Encoding.Default`). All depends on the file's content.

Comment: RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) eventually you have to convert  it like Jimi  said

Comment: You have data loss because you lost the knowledge of the character encoding of the file. We could help you guess. Please show some bytes and the corresponding expected characters, especially those with accents.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Write file:

```
RichTextBox1.SaveFile(PathToSave, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText)
```

Read file:

```
Dim OpenFile1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFile1.Filter = "Text Files (Txt Files)|*.txt"
    OpenFile1.Title = "Open a Text File"
    If (OpenFile1.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFile1.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    End If
```

Test on VS 2019